# What sin is committed in pastlife or this life so that one has to undergo KemeDrum Yog? Any remedy?

Tags: astrology, kundali

What sin is committed in pastlife or this life so that one has to undergo KemeDrum Yog? It is said that past life deeds cause such yog. So I want to understand why this yog is given in kundali? Any remedy to solve it?

It is believed that this yog is inauspicious and the person can either become too opulent by corruption or too poor by being impecunious. moreover, the planet moon has no other planet in order in horoscope which forms this yog. This yog is inauspicious. So we can understand some bad deeds must be there.

EDIT:

KemDrum Yog is formed in person's life is Moon in horoscope has no other auspicious planets but rahu or ketu in sequence.

Comment: Can u describe how  the yoga is formed?what are the planetary combinations involved?Also do u know its effect on a native?It will be better if u can add these details in ur Q.